# Dynamically handle channels to publish to with Redis in C++

Tags: c++, redis

I have 2 applications (a GUI in javascript and another in C++) which need to communicate to each other.

The C++ application (server) contains multiple realtime sensor data which it has to stream to the GUI (client). The data is buffered and sent as a big chunk. The GUI simply renders the data and doesn't buffer it locally (current library renders relatively slow).

We want to use Redis where each channel is a sensor. On the client side the user can select which sensor has to be streamed. This requires to let the server somehow know which channels to publish to.

Now the question is more about performance and extensibility. Which scenario is best?

1. Publish all sensor data. +-30 sensors with data at max 64 bit. Each up to 10,000 samples streamed at up to 50hz. (This is maxing out absolutely everything, but does give a ballpark).
2. Store the channel names in Redis as a JSON object or namespaced keys. Listen for a `set` event server-side, `get` the channels and cache them and dynamically publish to the channels.
3. Same as above but `get` the channels during every cycle from Redis without listening to any `set` event.
4. Use a `configuration` channel where the client publishes the configuration (via JSON string) when it's changed. Server side we subscribe to the `configuration` channel and handle the new channels appropriately.
5. Something else. Please elaborate.

Comment: Interesting question, I look forward to reading answers.  An observation: sensor data is append-only, which means it's ideal for caching (it never goes out of date) , and since data updates are regular, it's well suited for polling for updates after a given (last updated)  time.  There's no sense in an event / push based system if you know when the updates are going to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [redis streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro) feature from recently released redis 5.0. If you are looking for performant C++ library, which supports redis streams try to use [bredis](https://github.com/basiliscos/cpp-bredis), for example.

*disclaimer: I'm the author of bredis*